# Can't run Gradle Tasks on project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, liferay

I'm trying to run a Gradle Task by double clicking it on Eclipse, but the task is greyed out and says "Cannot run tasks for included builds" if I right click it as you can see in the image below:

[image: Gradle error]

What's that supposed to mean? Suddenly I can't run tasks for no apparent reason when I was able a few hours ago.

My project is Liferay based. I'm under JDK 1.8 and Windows 10.

I tried restarting Eclipse, cleaning project, deleting .gradle folder, changing Gradle version to 4.10 and refreshing tasks but nothing changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a solution, in case someone's having the same problem:

1. Copy project folder into another place
2. Delete project on Eclipse (check "Delete project contents on disk")
3. Delete *.gradle* folder inside the project folder
4. File > Import > Existing Gradle Project
5. Look for the project folder

Now you should be able to run Gradle Tasks again.

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 9):

Please consider the following (It works fine in my case):

1. Delete the project on eclipse (just check delete nested projects), **do not delete the project on the disk**
2. Go the the project on the disk, find and delete all **.project** files
3. Re-Import Liferay workspace on eclipse (File > Import > Liferay Workspace Project) and select your project folder

That did the trick ! Gradle tasks are now refreshed in green.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this in case it helps anyone.  For me, this problem arose when I added a new Java project and manually converted it to gradle and then added it as a sub-project.

Doing so changed the following line in /.settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs  from this:

```
connection.project.dir=
```

to this:

```
connection.project.dir=mynewproject
```

Once I changed that line back, I could run all sub-project tasks again.

Comment: Changed to `connection.project.dir=../..` in my case: relative path to main project from a sub-project.

Answer (score 0):

My project was set up as a Gradle multi-project. I found that the build tasks for the parent *and* nested projects were greyed out. The fix was to remove the Eclipse *Gradle Project Nature* ( Project Natures -> Gradle Project Nature) project nature on the parent project, delete the *.gradle* folder of the parent project and then add the *Gradle Project Nature* again via Eclipse.